# Can't run PHP exec command for ImageMagick within for loop

Tags: php, imagemagick

I need to write PHP script to call ImageMagick software I installed on my server (Windows server 2008 r2 with Apache server) to convert a group of TIFF format images into JPEG format.

I have already tried exec() with ImageMagick convert command for a single image and it's worked but when when I put exec() into a for loop to loop over a group of images, the PHP script seems to run forever until server timeout stop it.

```
$dir = "C:\\Apache24\htdocs\AutoRep\\img\\A101";
$files1 = scandir($dir);
$countarray = count($files1);
for ($x = 0; $x < $countarray; $x++){
  if (preg_match("/new/i", $files1[$x]) && preg_match("/VOP/i", $files1[$x])){
    $file_name = substr($files1[$x],0,-4); // to remove .tif from file name
    $command = "magick convert C:\Apache24\htdocs\AutoRep\\img\\A101\\$file_name.tif C:\Apache24\htdocs\AutoRep\\img\\A101\\$file_name.jpg";
    exec($command);
  }
}
```

I expect the script will convert the group of images from TIFF to JPEG format.

Comment: `scandir()` will return `.` and `..` you should `continue` if `in_array($files1[$x], ['.','..']);`

Comment: @zanderwar they already don't match the preg_match that is already in place tho, as `.` or `..` don't contain 'new' or 'VOP'

Comment: Do you get any image converted at all tho? Don't forget to escape all you backslashes. You only escape a few for now.

Comment: Write a PHP loop for each image that calls Imagemagick convert in an exec() command. Or use PHP Imagick and the PHP looping.

Comment: You almost never want to use `magick` followed by `convert`. Use just `magick` with v7 and just `convert` with v6.

Comment: I think ImageMagick gets confused with Windows drive specifiers like `C:\\` Maybe try a forward slash instead.

Answer (score 2):

I would put your input and output strings into a variable so you can echo them to see they contain what you expect.

Why are you removing .tif then adding it back?

You do not need convert with magick.

On Windows I always put the file path within " " to contain it.

I am not sure if you need to escape \ but echoing your variable should prove that.

Try adding some error reporting by writing this into your code:

```
$array=array();
echo "<pre>";
exec("magick Input Output 2>&1", $array); // Your Imagemagick command
echo "<br>".print_r($array)."<br>"; 
echo "</pre>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `mogrify` command. Have a look at the [docs](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/mogrify.php)

This will convert all the images in the folder to the new format and is much faster.

```
mogrify -format jpg *.tif
```

Comment: how does that answer the question?

Comment: Its a solution to what needs to be done : convert a batch of images to jpg. Since a single conversion takes time, you cannot really do a loop neatly, as you need to wait for the conversion to complete ( or spawn multiple instances of im). The given solution is intended to be used in cases of batch conversion.

Comment: it's not, the OP is already using `convert` and won't overwrite files anyway as he's converting from tiff to jpeg. Also, he only wants to convert the files containing `new` or `VOP` in their name so the mask `*.tif` is wrong. There's no context provided at all, just "use that". It doesn't solve the current problem nor answers the OP's needs. The issue is in the way the command is executed, not what commend is used.